# Regular expression to match content within curly braces without nested braces breaking it

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently matching content within a set of curly braces using `{([^}]*)}`, but it stops working once I add closing other curly braces inside of it.

I basically want the double curly braces to act as any other text and be apart of the matching group it's nested in, **not a separate match or sub-match (not recursive)**.

```
{
    <div>
    works
    </div>
}

{
    <div>
    {{fails}}
    </div>
}
```

Here's a live example of what I currently have: http://regex101.com/r/pT5fA1/4

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for that:

```
{((?:[^{}]|{{[^}]*}})*)}
```

Pattern details:

```
{(
(?:               # non capturing group
    [^{}]         # all that is not a curly bracket
  |               # OR
    {{[^}]*}}     # a string inside double curly brackets
)*                # zero or more times
)}
```

A more efficient way to do it consits to use an [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html):

```
{((?>[^{}]+|{{[^}]*}})*)}
```

Unfortunatly, Javascript doesn't have this feature. But you can emulate it with a trick that use the fact that the content of a lookahead is naturally atomic:

```
{((?:(?=([^{}]+|{{[^}]*}}))\2)*)}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much. Been trying at it for hours. Quick question, and probably not possible, but is there a method using this layout that would allow random brackets within the main capturing group as well?

Comment: @Matthew: You can't with javascript regex, since it doesn't have the recursion feature. The way to do it, is to parse the string and to increment and decrement a variable when you encounter a curly bracket. When the variable is equal to zero, curly brackets are balanced.

Comment: I figured as much. Thanks for the suggestion and the patterns above. Really appreciate it!